# Flask url not working

Tags: python, flask

I am working on flask app which has below code in views.py:

```
@bp.route('/talents/filters', methods=['POST'])
def talents_filters():
    form = TalentFilters()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        set_filters(form)
    return redirect_back('.home')

@bp.route('/talents/filters/reset<path:uri>')
def talents_filters_reset(uri):
    return session['filters'][uri]
```

The first url is working fine. But the second one is giving 404 error.

First one works on

```
http://localhost:5000/admin/talents/filters
```

For second I am trying url

```
http://localhost:5000/admin/talents/filters/reset?uri=%2Fadmin%2Ftalents%2F
```

It is giving 404 NOT FOUND status code. I am completely clueless. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[URL query parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) (everything after the `?`) are **not** part of the path. They are not captured by `<path:uri>`; that parameter expects to find a path element starting with a `/` instead.

Use:

```
@bp.route('/talents/filters/reset')
def talents_filters_reset():
    uri = request.args['uri']
    return session['filters'][uri]
```

instead, where [`request.args`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.args) contains all parsed request parameters.